# Yii2: how to set the default action into the controller

Tags: php, yii2

I know how to set the default controller/action into the configuration by the `defaultRoute` option

```
'defaultRoute'        => 'home/index'
```

But I don't how do it with the action into the current controller.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution.

```
class MyController extends Controller {
     public $defaultAction = 'my-action';
}
```